# Incrementing char pointers in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, char

Why does the program,

```
char *s, *p, c;

s = "abc";

printf(" Element 1 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", *s);
printf(" Element 2 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", *s+1);
printf(" Element 3 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", *s+2);
printf(" Element 4 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", *s+3);
printf(" Element 5 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", s[3]);
printf(" Element 4 pointed to by S is '%c'\n", *s+4);
```

give the following results?

```
 Element 1 pointed to by S is 'a'
 Element 2 pointed to by S is 'b'
 Element 3 pointed to by S is 'c'
 Element 4 pointed to by S is 'd'
 Element 5 pointed to by S is ' '
 Element 4 pointed to by S is 'e'
```

How did the compiler continue the sequence? And why does `s[3]` return an empty value?

Comment: Precedence. You want `*(s+1)` etc. But `*(s+4)` would be undefined behaviour.

Comment: `s[3]` returns the 4'th character (they're indexed from 0), which is a string terminating `\0` character.

Comment: `s[3]` is `\0`, so it shows none

Comment: I'm skeptical of that Element 5 output - there should be no space between the quotation marks.

Comment: By the way, if you're coding in C++ and not plain C - don't use `printf`. `std::cout` (from header file `<iostream>`) is safer, easier to use and less error-prone.

Answer (score 9):

It doesn't continue the sequence. You are doing `*s+3` which first dereferences `s` to give you the `char` with value `'a'`, and then you are adding on to that `char` value. Adding 3 to `'a'` gives you the value of `'d'` (at least in your execution character set).

If you change them to `*(s+1)` and so on, you'll get the undefined behaviour which is expected.

`s[3]` accesses the last element of the string which is the null character.

Comment: One tip - `"abc"` often isn't a good test string - it's too easy to get the expected result (or something confusingly close) accidentally from incorrect code.

Answer (score 2):

Notice that `*s` is a character, which is essentially a number. Adding another number to it, results in a character with a higher ASCII value.
The `s[3]` is empty, because you only assigned "abc" to entries 0,1,2 respectively. In fact the 3rd character is the '\0' character.